# Single word which means "keep moving forward"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a single word which means "keep moving forward".
What are my options?

I need word as

persevere
Be persistent, refuse to stop

cognizant
(sometimes followed by 'of') having or showing knowledge or understanding or realization or perception

[]
keep moving forward

I want to make meaningful name for firm

please help me

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide us with some context as to where you would like to use such a word. Could you perhaps outline a few sentences where it would go?

Comment: "persevere"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about *propel*, *impel*, or *journey*?

Answer (score 3):

There's [Mush!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushing) (from Fr. *marchez*, "walk"), particularly used to drive huskies through snow. Largely supplanted now by *"Hike!"*, according to that Wikipedia link.

If OP intends a more metaphoric sense, **advance** or **progress** would still fit the bill.